# Placing two views side-by-side

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a web app that shows a side menu bar and renders a chart like below:-
I want both components (sidebar menu and chart) to be placed side by side. Currently, the chart is being rendered following the sidebar menu i.e., chart is rendered below it. Is it possible to render them side-by-side?
[image: Web app looks like this]

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import "./styles.css";
import { Chart } from "chart.js";
import moment from "moment";
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { ProSidebar, Menu, MenuItem, SubMenu } from 'react-pro-sidebar';
import 'react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.levelsArr = [
      "Jan",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "April",
      "May",
      "June",
      "July",
      "Aug"
    ];
    this.chartData = {
      dataSet1: Array.from(
        { length: 8 },
        () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 590) + 10
      ),
      dataSet2: Array.from(
        { length: 8 },
        () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 590) + 10
      )
    };
    this.state = {
      months: [
        { month: "Jan", value: "0" },
        { month: "Feb", value: "1" },
        { month: "Mar", value: "2" },
        { month: "Apr", value: "3" },
        { month: "May", value: "4" },
        { month: "Jun", value: "5" },
        { month: "Jul", value: "6" },
        { month: "Aug", value: "7" }
      ],
      from: "0",
      toMonth: "7",
      filterLimit: 100,
      sidebarOpen: true,
      sidebar: false
    };
    this.onSetSidebarOpen = this.onSetSidebarOpen.bind(this);
    this.sidebar = this.showSidebar.bind(this);
  }
  onSetSidebarOpen(open) {
    this.setState({ sidebarOpen: open });
  }
  showSidebar(sidebar) {
    this.setState({sidebar: !sidebar});
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.barChart = new Chart("bar", {
      type: "bar",
      options: {
        responsive: true,
        title: {
          display: true,
          text: "Student Admission Data"
        }
      },
      data: {
        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "April", "May", "June", "July", "Aug"],
        datasets: [
          {
            type: "bar",
            label: "School 1",
            data: this.chartData.dataSet1,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(20,200,10,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(20,200,10,0.4)",
            fill: false
          },
          {
            type: "bar",
            label: "School 2",
            data: this.chartData.dataSet2,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(100,189,200,0.4)",
            borderColor: "rgba(100,189,200,0.4)",
            fill: false
          }
        ]
      }
    });
  }
  applyFilter() {
    //console.log(this.chartData.dataSet1);
    const value = this.state.filterLimit;
    const lessThanOrGreaterThan = this.state.lessThanOrGreaterThan;
    console.log(lessThanOrGreaterThan);
    this.barChart.data.datasets[0].data = this.chartData.dataSet1;
    this.barChart.data.datasets[1].data = this.chartData.dataSet2;

    this.barChart.data.datasets.forEach((data, i) => {
      if (lessThanOrGreaterThan === "greaterThan") {
        this.barChart.data.datasets[i].data = data.data.map((v) => {
          if (v >= value) return v;
          else return 0;
        });
        // console.log(">>>>>>>>", this.barChart.data.datasets[i].data);
      } else {
        this.barChart.data.datasets[i].data = data.data.map((v) => {
          if (v <= value) return v;
          else return 0;
        });
        //console.log("?????????", this.barChart.data.datasets[i].data);
      }
    });
    this.barChart.update();
  }
  applyDateFilter() {
    this.barChart.data.labels = this.levelsArr.slice(
      parseInt(this.state.from),
      parseInt(this.state.toMonth) + 1
    );
    this.barChart.update();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="chart-diplay">
        <div>
          <React.StrictMode>
          <div class="divSideBar">
          <ProSidebar >
          <Menu iconShape="square">
            <MenuItem>
            <select
            id="lessThanOrGreaterThan"
            value={this.state.lessThanOrGreaterThan}
            onChange={(e) =>
              this.setState({ lessThanOrGreaterThan: e.currentTarget.value })
            }
          >
            <option value="lessThan">Less Than</option>
            <option value="greaterThan">Greater Than</option>
          </select>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>
            <input
            id="filterLimit"
            placeholder="Filter Limit"
            value={this.state.filterLimit}
            onChange={(e) => this.setState({ filterLimit: e.target.value })}
          ></input>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem>
            <button class="button" onClick={() => this.applyFilter()}>
            Apply Filter
          </button>
            </MenuItem>
              <MenuItem>
              <div>
            <select
              id="from"
              value={this.state.from}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ from: e.target.value })}
            >
              {this.state.months.map((el) => (
                <option value={el.value} key={el}>
                  {" "}
                  {el.month}{" "}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <select
              id="toMonth"
              value={this.state.toMonth}
              onChange={(e) => this.setState({ toMonth: e.target.value })}
            >
              {this.state.months.map((el) => (
                <option value={el.value} key={el}>
                  {" "}
                  {el.month}{" "}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
            </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem>
          <button class="button" onClick={() => this.applyDateFilter()}>
            Date Filter
          </button>
          </MenuItem>
          </Menu>
        </ProSidebar>
        </div>
        <div class="divBar">
        <canvas id="bar"></canvas>
        </div>
        </React.StrictMode>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want the filters to still be functional, even after editing the app.

Comment: Wrap your components in a div and use flexbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do

```
<div className = 'container'>
       <SideBar/>
       <chart/>
</div>
```

in your css file :

```
.container {
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: row or column 
}
```